# jq: Delete objects from an array based on its key

Tags: json, jq

I want to use jq to delete all objects from an array whose key does not correspond to a defined value.

This is my JSON:

```json
{
  "name": "config1",
  "children": [
    {
      "customer": {
        "name": "cust1"
      }
    },
    {
      "filter": {
        "name": "test1"
      }
    },
    {
      "filter": {
        "name": "test2"
      }
    },
    {
      "context": {
        "id": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For example I want to remove all objects whose key is not "filter". Desired output:

```json
{
  "name": "config1",
  "children": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "name": "test1"
      }
    },
    {
      "filter": {
        "name": "test2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried

```
jq 'del(.children[] | with_entries(select(.key != "filter")))'
```

but that gives the following error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Invalid path expression near attempt to iterate through ["customer"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq 'del(.children[] | select(.filter == null))'
```

Check it [online](https://jqplay.org/s/1QA-daSKN_).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_entries` function such as

```
jq 'del(.children[] | select( to_entries[] | .key != "filter"))'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EyRERl0qbK)</kbd>

Comment: jq version 1.5-1 produces an error: ```jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Invalid path expression near attempt to iterate through ["customer"]```. In jq version 1.6 this works fine.

Comment: well, OK, as there were no mention about the version within the question I replied so ... @Jurc